# How do I escape a left paren in a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, shell, replace

If I have a file containing some escaped parens, how can I replace all instances with an unescaped paren using Perl?

i.e. turn this:

```
.... foo\(bar ....
```

into this

```
.... foo(bar ....
```

I tried the following but receivied this error message:

```
perl -pe "s/\\\(/\(/g" ./file
Unmatched ( in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\\( <-- HERE / at -e line 1.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're forgetting that backslashes mean something to the shell, too.  Try using single quotes instead of double quotes.  (Or put your script in a file, where you won't need to worry about shell quoting.)

Comment: Gah, can't believe I didn't think of that. Friday can't come soon enough.

Answer (score 6):

Gah.  From command line, no less.  Way too many levels of metacharacter interpretation.

Try replacing your double quotes with single quotes, see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, you're about 8 seconds behind the earlier answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[cjm's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8355/cjm) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567344/how-do-i-unescape-a-left-paren-in-perl/567374#567374) is probably the best.  If you must do it at the command line, try using [quotemeta()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) or the [metaquoting escape sequence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) **(\Q...\E)**.  This worked for me in a bash prompt:

```
perl -pe "s/\Q\(\E/(/g" ./file
```